# Single page with callback and postback

Tags: asp.net, postback

I have never used an ASP.NET callback as described here: [Difference between a Postback and a Callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365100/difference-between-a-postback-and-a-callback).

Can a webpage use callbacks and Postbacks or are they mutually exclusive i.e. one or the other? I have spent some time researching this but I cannot find an answer to my specific question.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET web page can have the callback and postback both . It is just how you are going to use it. Callback is nothing but old way of making AJAX call in .net framework . For some feature like the lightweight one you can go for call back and other one you can go for full post back.It is similar like in normal webpage you can postback the data if you add the form tag and on the same page you have normal AJAX call to update some part of html .

Comment: Can you have a callback contained a button.click event?

Comment: yes you can have , you just need to return false so that postback is fired.

Comment: Could you provide an example? I don't understand what you mean by "return false".  Thanks.

Comment: I think I found the answer to my comment question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547945/disable-postback-at-click-on-a-button