# How to call button onclick using javascript and stop postback

Tags: javascript

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1) {
    $("#ExcelReportHolder").tableExport({
        formats: ["xlsx"],
        fileName: $('#<%=hdnReportName.ClientID%>').val()
    });
    $("#ExcelReportHolder Button").click();


}
```

this is the button which is hidden and i want to click that button but want to stop post back.plz Help. thank u.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide necessary details, Also please break down your problem statement and search google

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable postback at click on a button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547945/disable-postback-at-click-on-a-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind a click handler and prevent the default action using [`event.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) method or by returning `false`.

```
$("#ExcelReportHolder button").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // or
  // return false;

  // do the rest

}).click();
```

Comment: $("#ExcelReportHolder button").click(function(){ Return false;});                       Works fine!

Comment: Yup Thank u @Pranav C Balan